# Entering fullscreen mode hides the icon from taskbar and the application runs from background

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

When I made a window go into fullscreen mode, the application icon was hidden from the taskbar (after doing alt-tab). It also didn't appear in the `alt+tab` windows. It only showed the other windows that I had open.

When I checked task manager, the python process was under the `background processes` category. I couldn't switch back to the window.

How can I stop the application from running in the background when I enter fullscreen mode?

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello fullscreen world")

        label = QLabel("Hello fullscreen world")

        # The `Qt` namespace has a lot of attributes to customise
        # widgets. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Set the central widget of the Window. Widget will expand
        # to take up all the space in the window by default.
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        
        self.shortcut_close_window = QShortcut(QKeySequence('F11'), self)
        self.shortcut_close_window.activated.connect(self.goFullscreen)
    def goFullscreen(self):
        if self.isFullScreen():
            self.setWindowFlags(self._flags)
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self._flags = self.windowFlags()
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowType_Mask)
            self.showFullScreen()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Note: even terminating the process using ctrl+c or closing command prompt doesn't work, only task manager does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `self.setWindowFlags` in `goFullscreen()` function. It is unnecessary.

```py
def goFullscreen(self):
        if self.isFullScreen():
            #self.setWindowFlags(self._flags)
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            #self._flags = self.windowFlags()
            #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowType_Mask)
            self.showFullScreen()
```

Btw, the reason is that you use the Qt.WindowType_Mask flag.

> WindowType_Mask: A mask for extracting the window type part of the
> window flags.

> [~Window Flags~](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

---

I had no idea that there was such a strange bug in Ubuntu. So all you have to do is write your own FullScreen method:

(I don't use ubuntu. So I don't know if you will run into a bug again.)

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    isfullscreen = False
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello fullscreen world")

        self._flags = self.windowFlags()
        self._geometry = ((self.screen().size().width() / 2) - (self.width() / 2),
                          (self.screen().size().height() / 2) - (self.height() / 2), 600, 400)

        self.setGeometry(*self._geometry)

        label = QLabel("Hello fullscreen world")


        # The `Qt` namespace has a lot of attributes to customise
        # widgets. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Set the central widget of the Window. Widget will expand
        # to take up all the space in the window by default.
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        self.shortcut_close_window = QShortcut(QKeySequence('F11'), self)
        self.shortcut_close_window.activated.connect(self.goShowFullScreen)
        self._geometry = self.geometry()

    def goShowFullScreen(self):
        if not self.isfullscreen:
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.setGeometry(self.screen().geometry())
            self.show()
            self.isfullscreen = True
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.setGeometry(self._geometry)
            self.show()
            self.isfullscreen = False


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: I used setWindowFlags because someone on StackOverflow mentioned that fullscreen doesn't work on ubuntu

Comment: and the other set window flags is because the close button hides without it